# How ot install ubuntu on a USB stick and make 100% sure you won't mess your internal HDD install?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive, live-usb

I learned the hard way that when you install ubuntu to a usb stick it messes up your boot partition and the install of your internal hdd can't run anymore.

Well, what is 100% fool proof way to simply install it to a usb stick (usb hdd whatever) and not mess your internal install?

Most tutorials advise you to disconnect your HDD as a 100% fool proof way. Well I'm with laptop that makes that very hard.

Other tutorials advise using Virtual Box and install guest addons to make it see the USB and install it then. Well that seems like an overkill and involves installing non-free software.

So, isn't there some simple solution? I mean that seems like easy enough task, right?

Right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing a complete Ubuntu system to your memory stick, you should install a live image with persistence enabled (i.e. files in the home folder are kept). You can do this by running:

```
gksudo usb-creator-gtk
```

Then, choose the Ubuntu ISO image, and choose the amount of space you want to be reserved for persistence.

You may need to install the program first for this to work. If you get an error or nothing opens, run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

When it's finished installing, run the original command again.

If you're doing this from Windows, you can use the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to achieve the same result. Just chooose the ISO image and the USB stick, and choose the amount of persistence you want.

Comment: Can you install stuff to live USB with persistence? Actually what is the difference between installed and live USB with persistence?

Comment: You can't install packages with APT but you can download portable packages and extract them somewhere in your home folder and they'll stay. Maybe try Homebrew? brew.sh/linuxbrew

Comment: I don't really see your point at why I shoud go through all the extra hassle instead of just having installed ubuntu on a USB as I would have it installed on a HDD. Especially with USB 3.0 it works actually better then some HDDs.

Comment: @user240891 Are you trying to tell us that USB 3.0 is better than sATA? If so, then that's a very bold statement

Comment: I get 130mb/s read and 40 mb/s write on some USB 3.0 @Davide, how much you get on a 5400rpm hdd for example?  And lets talk about average sized files just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to install an OS in any portable media, mostly because of performance issues, but also because of boot manager issues as you described.

That being said, I'd use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a live usb, which is probably what you want anyway. Just make sure to follow the (simple) instructions, and nothing bad will happen.

Comment: First, it has it's uses but thanks for the advice... Second, I don't want live usb BUT installed one. OMG

Comment: About your performance concerns, have you heard about USB 3.0 @Davide ?

Comment: My performance concerns are mostly these: `a drive that could read large files at 68 MB/s and write at 46 MB/s, could only manage 14 MB/s and 0.3 MB/s with many small files` [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive#File_transfer_speeds)

Comment: I've run installed systems from USB 3.0 and they run great. Really. Actually even at USB 2.0 is doable for someone needs. Saying someone doesn't need that but live install is like someone asking for apples and you saying, "Nah, that is not good for you, here have some oranges instead" Honestly it doesn't look good :)

Comment: Let me put it differently then. If what you want was a good idea, the Internet would have been filed with tutorials. Also,  do you expect to plug in you "OS stick" on different hardware and it'll just work fine? Don't you think there might be "some" issues with drivers, partitions, screen resolution, networks, unplugging the USB cord... I'm sure you'll eventually see what I mean